# Where are the log files located in Moodle?

Tags: file, logging, moodle

I need to locate where the logging data is stored in Moodle. In the Moodle database there is a table called 'log' where log data is stored. However, I can get Moodle reports showing logging data that is definitely NOT stored in this table. I am using Moodle version 2.7.8.

Comment: As it usually happens in php applications, logs are not used. You could try this https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=316343 Low level logs could be located in apache or nginx logs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Moodle version I am using (2.7.8) you have three possibilities to log your data (called 'log stores'):

1. **Standard log**: This is the default possibility. All the log data will be saved to the database table 'logstore_standard_log'. You can see here for example when a user has viewed a particular course, when a user has logged into the system, or logged out, etc.
2. **Legacy log**: This is a log structure used in earlier versions of Moodle. All the log data have been saved to the database table 'log'.
3. **External database**: you have here the possibility to choose and configure an external database in order to store your log data. The database connection, name, and other settings may be configured under Site administration->Plugins->Logging->Manage log stores->External database log settings.

Current information on logging can be found at:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Logging_2